# How to restrict a bone tail from coming too close to some region?

Tags: bones, cloth-simulation, pose-mode, collision

So I have the following character. The shirt and shorts use cloth simulation.
[image]

I need to load different poses programatically on it and take renders. However sometimes it happens that one a given pose the hands interferes with the clothes. Like here:

[image]

Do anyone have an idea of how to solve it? I would like either to disable collision only with the arms (so that it would get through the body but at least wouldnt destroy the clothes simulation), or guarantee that the arms will not get too close to the body.

Answer (score 1):

Your example has details that make things difficult, but your explicit question is answerable.

If you want to prevent a bone tail from a region, you use the first bone as a guide for another bone, which is excluded from that region, and then you use a third bone to damped track the tracker.

For example, if you wanted to exclude forearm.R from entering with 0.25 units of the head of hip.R, you would disable deform on forearm.R, extrude a bone from the tail of forearm.R, disconnect that bone, give that extruded bone forearm.R.001 a limit distance constraint, set to 0.25 units outside, targeting hip.R, then you'd duplicate forearm.R to forearm.R.002, parent forearm.R.002 to forearm.R, enable deform on this forearm.R.002, and give it a damped track constraint targeting forearm.R.001. Here's a pic:

[image]

Note that "limit distance" is merely one way we can exclude a bone from a region.  A shrinkwrap constraint is another way to do this.  And we don't have to shrinkwrap to rendering meshes, but can shrinkwrap to any mesh we want.

It's often good to use booleans of simple primitives like spheres to create limited spaces for bones.  If we look at the pic above, we see that the tail of forearm.R.002 is not actually at the location of the tail, because the tail moved directly away from the head of hip.R.  The more accurate solution would be shrinkwrap it to the surface (solidify modifier) of a boolean subtraction of two spheres: a sphere parented to forearm.R, representing its normal range of rotation, minus a sphere parented to hip.R, representing the distance from which we want to restrict its tail from entering.  This is obviously more complicated, and if the simpler solution is good enough, then the simpler solution is fine.

However, what we can't do is shrinkwrap to the mesh we're deforming, because that creates a dependency loop.  That's the main reason your example is difficult.  You *could* separate the arm object to a different object and remove the forearm group from the main object, which would clear up this dependency.

But really: this is complicated and, usually, a bad idea!  This isn't something that magically makes everything okay, it's just a technique, occasionally useful, that answers the explicit question.  The right way to solve this problem is to not animate the arm like that in the first place.  Just fix the pose so that it doesn't clip.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer. It is very helpful! Indeed, the problem is quite tricky. I know it seems much easier to simply not animating the arm like that, the problem is that I need to read a database with thousands of different poses obtained by pose estimation models on real people and load them into my model. Because of that, I cant go through each pose and guarantee that they are fine.

Comment: I think i ll have to either separate the arm to a different object (I didnt want to do that because it will complicate somewhat python code that I have to run haha), or simply I ll give up using a cloth simulation and treat the clothes a normal mesh